# Get the ENTER click event of input when type="number"

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, input, onkeyup

In the HTML **input text**, using the *onKeyUp* method I am able to catch the *click event* on enter button when input ***type***="**text**" .

But the same event is not able to fire if the input **type="number"**.

**HTML**

```
<input id="inputLocation" type="text" class="inputBarCode" style="text-transform: uppercase" placeholder: placeholder/>
```

**JS**

```
 $('#inputLocation').keyup(function (e) {
     if (e.which === 13) {
         $('#inputLocation').blur();
         //self.executeLocationLookup();
         alert("Event ", e.which);
     }
 });
```

Can you please let me know how to get the click event(13) of the enter button if input type is ***numeric keyboard***

[image: Please Refer the attached image]

Comment: Chrome on Android 8 returns 13, as you'd expect.

Answer (score 0):

Use `event.target.value` property or `$(this).val()`

```
$('#inputLocation').keyup(function (e) {
  if (e.which === 13 && isNumber(e.target.value)) {
     $('#inputLocation').blur();
     //self.executeLocationLookup();
     alert("Event ", e.which);
  }
});  

function isNumber(n) {
   return !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is better to actually listen to the `submit` event, which is triggered when the enter key is pressed.

Use the following markup:

```
<form>
    <input id="inputLocation" type="text" class="inputBarCode" style="text-transform: uppercase" placeholder: placeholder/>
</form>
```

and you can use [`submit()`](https://api.jquery.com/submit/) to listen for the submit event.

```
$('form').submit(function (e) {
    // prevent the page from auto-navigating on form submit
    e.preventDefault();

    // do something
});
```